# IndexError: list index out of range when no argument is supplied

Tags: python, sys

I just want to know why this code is generating `IndexError: list index out of range` when no argument supplied to it?

script.py

```
import sys
a = sys.argv[1]
print(a)
```

Sample output with argument/s

```
user@linux:~$ python3 script.py abc
abc
user@linux:~$ python3 script.py abc def
abc
user@linux:~$
```

Sample output without argument/s

```
user@linux:~$ python3 script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
    a = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
user@linux:~$
```

My reference: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv

Comment: `sys.argv` is the list containing all the command line arguments. In your case, there is only one argument, the script name, so no argument at index `[1]` and therefore the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the python docs `sys.argv` returns:

> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. argv[0]
> is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a
> full pathname or not).

The problem is that when you run your script without arguments like `python3 script.py`, you are trying to access the element at `index 1` by using `sys.argv[1]` but in fact this element doesn't even exists in the list.
Therefore, The python interpreter throws an `IndexError`.

Answer (score 0):

List `sys.argv` contains your command line arguments (index 0 is command itself, rest are arguments). So, if you won't provide argument then list contains only one item (only `sys.argv[0]` is there).

[Here's](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sys.html#sys.argv) official Python documentation.